# Three divs in one row and fourth in the second row

Tags: html, css

I need to have three divs in a row and fourth div displayed below these divs. 
See the layout https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vJoP.jpg (just illustration)

I've tried to use display block for the parent div mixed with display inline/inline-block for these three divs and some other settings but it always breaks first row and displays these divs in block.
Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What code have you tried to run? You can edit your question to include more information.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `display:inline` on a div, a simpler solution might be using the `float` property in CSS. With the help of adding a `width` and `height` we can make complex layouts:

```css
html, body{
  margin:0; padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#48c;
}

#container{
  height:50%;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
}

.rect{ float:left; height:100%; }
#box1{ width:50%; background:#999; }
#box2{ width:25%; background:#666; }
#box3{ width:25%; background:#333; }
#box4{ width:100%; background:#000; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="rect" id="box1"></div>
    <div class="rect" id="box2"></div>
    <div class="rect" id="box3"></div>
    <div class="rect" id="box4"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simple and effective Solution would be CSS Table layout**

HTML

```css
.Row 
{
    display: table;
     width: 100%;
     table-layout: fixed;
     border-spacing: 7px; 
} 

.Column 
{
     display: table-cell;
     background-color: gray; 
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
     <div class="Column">First</div>
     <div class="Column">Second</div>
     <div class="Column">Third</div> 
</div> 
<div class="Row">
     <div class="Column">Fourth</div>
     <div class="Column">Fifth</div>
     <div class="Column">Sixth</div> 
</div>
```