# Placing div container horizontally in html

Tags: html

I am completely new to HTML and struggling to know how to place align div tags  or position containers horizontally. By default, div containers are placed vertically.

From what I found in different links were nested `divs` that look something like this :

```
 <div id="ParentContainer" style="height:100%; width:100%; overflow: hidden;"> 
    <div id="chart_div" style="float: left; width:50%;">Left Side Menu</div>
    <div id="chart_div2" style="float: left; width:50%; ">Random Content</div>
   </div>
```

If this is how I do it, how do I refer to `chart_div` and `chart_div2` ?

Before this, I could refer them directly with div id to place elements at that particular location.Please suggest simplest possible solution as I am completely new to  html and infact simplest CSS confuses me.

Edit:

```
<div id="ParentContainer" style="height:100%; width:100%; overflow: hidden;"> 
    <div id="chart_div" style="float: left; width:50%; display:inline ;">Left</div>
    <div id="chart_div2" style="float: left; width:50%; display:inline ;">Random</div>
   </div>
```

How do I refer them now ? Is it just `chart_div` or something like `ParentContainer.chart_div` ?

**Edit 2 :**

```
 <div id="chart_div" style="float: left; width:50%; display:inline ;">Left</div>
    <div id="chart_div2" style="float: right; width:50%; display:inline ;">Random</div>
```

Comment: "refer them" in what way? CSS or Javascript?

Comment: @LynelHudson: Using javascript. the method that I use if getElementById(divId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using floats to horizontally align divs is one of the simplest ways to create complex layouts with HTML and CSS. When floating divs you should almost always apply a width to the div in question. A detailed example here: [Three divs in one row and fourth in the second row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334410/three-divs-in-one-row-and-fourth-in-the-second-row/29334447#29334447)

**Edit:** If you are asking how to select those divs in your javascript, a simple method would be to use `getElementById( 'chart_div' )` and `getElementById( 'chart_div2' )` respectively.

Comment: I am using getElementById. I mean to ask that if I am using nested divs , how do I use their Id here ? Just div id for inner div containers as well ?

Comment: You can still use `getElementById` even if the div is nested. I'm still not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm if I am allowed to do it the same way. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, no problem. `getElementById` is probably the most common way to access elements and it doesn't depend on layout in any way.

Answer (score 0):

try adding display: inline

for example:

Left Side Menu

You also have a extra ; on the second tag.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to float the div's horizontally if so

```
<div id="chart_div" style="float: left; width:50; ;">Left Side Menu</div>
```

Correct the inline style **width** and don't forget to modify parent div margin and padding.
Set div chart_div **Float Left** and chart_div2 **Float Right** then you will achieve what you are looking for.
Another option to use bootstrap which give you great control over your layout.

I'm sending you my code which I was able to float the div's correctly copy my code and save it as HTML then check it out.

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">#parent{width: 100%;height: 100%;overflow: hidden;background-color: red;}#child1{float: left;width: 50%;height: 50%;display: inline;background-color: blue;}#child2{float: left;width: 50%;height: 50%;display: inline;background-color: yellow;}</style></head><body><div id="parent"><div id="child1">child1</div><div id="child2">child2</div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Could you please check the edit2 and confirm if this is what you meant?I still do not see the container aligned horizontally  though.

Comment: Simran check my code you will see how to acheive what you are looking for using HTML and CSS only no javascript required. And you can keep adding as many as you want div's horizontally if you set the width correctly such as 3 floating div's 100% / 3 = 33.33% each if 4 div's 100% / 4 = 25% each and so on hopefully my code helps you.